# How do I use toggle in react with states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Having problem to find the solution of using state in React.

I've not done it with bind-method because I'd rather to make it work this way with arrow-functions.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    };
}

toggleNavbar = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isOpen: !prevState.isOpen;
    });
}

render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

return (
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a className="navbar-brand mr-4" href="">Do you want to build sowman?</a>
    <button
      className="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      onclick={() => this.toggleNavbar()}>
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
    </button>
    <div
      className="collapse navbar-collapse"
      id="navbarSupportedContent"
      isOpen={isOpen}>
```

I want the toggle-button to show/hide the div that's comming ahead.(This is just a sample of the text and won't work on its own)

Comment: so what's the issue?

Comment: inside `<div style={{display: isOpen ? 'block':'none'}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to toggle your div based on state, you can either:

1. Remove the semicolon `;` from your setState property inside `toggleNavbar`.
2. React does not allow camelcase writing for attribute names. Change `isOpen` to `isopen` in your `#navbarSupportedContent` div.
3. Specify a string instead of a boolean as your `isopen` attribute value and based on that, change the css of the div accordingly.

You can check out a practical example with css and html of the above in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/pqabVv) or you can check the React class component code in the **Code Snippet** below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggleNavbar = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleNavbar}>Click Me</button>
                <div id="navbarSupportedContent" isopen={isOpen ? "open" : "close"}>
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

---

Or you can use the `&& operator` as @ŁukaszBlaszyński showed above by:

1. Removing the semicolon `;` from your setState property inside `toggleNavbar`.
2. Use the `&& operator` to toggle the div depending on the `isOpen` state property.

You can check out a practical example of the above in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/ZVrpOK) or you can check the React class component code in the **Code Snippet** below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggleNavbar = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleNavbar}>Click Me</button>
                {isOpen && <div id="navbarSupportedContent" >
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                </div>}
            </div>
        )
    }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This made sense to me in my head :) I didn't understand I had to USE the prop afterwards... I thought if it's false, it won't show and if it's true it'll show. I know Reactstrap uses it that way. But I guess I'll manually have to do it. Is there any way to do it with bootstrap class-system if it's true/false (so that I don't have to write the rules in a separate file)?

Comment: Glad I could help man. And I'll try fiddling with the code and see if we can use the bootstrap class system or not to toggle the div.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using arrow functions, you just can define your property like :

```
onclick={this.toggleNavbar}>
```

and not making another arrow function inside propery

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle it works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/y5gqrf02/1/

Example code which simple toggle state and display message or not based on state. It use arrow function and simply take state isOpen negation to be updated.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
      this.setState({
          isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
      });
  }

  render() {
      const { isOpen } = this.state;

      return (
         <div onClick={() => this.toggleNavbar()}>Click Me 
           {isOpen && <div>IS OPEN</div>}
         </div>
      );

  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```